# How I can enforce in-memory file io during testing?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I am making a class for saving some user-provided settings to my application:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

class UserSettings
{
   late final String _path;
   UserSettings(){
      String os = Platform.operatingSystem;
      String home = "";
      Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
      if (Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isLinux) {
        home = envVars['HOME'] as String;
      } else if (Platform.isWindows) {
        home = envVars['UserProfile'] as String;
      }

      _path = p.join(home, ".settings.json");
   }

   Future<Map<String, dynamic>> readSettings(File? settingFile) {
   
       if (settingFile == null) {
        settingsFile = File(_path);
      }

      if (!settingsFile.exists()) {
        return new Map<String, dynamic>();
      }

      String json = settingsFile.readAsString();
      Map<String, dynamic> settings = Map.castFrom(json.decode(json));

      return settings;
   }

   Future<Map<String, dynamic>> writeSettings(Strikg key, dynamic value) {
      File settingsFile = File(_path);
      Map<String,dynamic> settings = await readSettings();

      settings[key] = value;
      await settingsFile.writeAsString(json.encode(jsonData));
   }
}
```

And I want to test whether class is able to read and write the file correctly:

```dart
test('Test that accesstoken and Store is is written', () async {
    UserSettings settings = UserSettings();
    
    settings.writeSettings('mytoken','somevalue');
    settings.saveStoreId('myid',522);

    Map<String,dynamic> settings = settings.readSettings(null);

    assert(settings['store_id']==522,'Is is not saved');
    assert(settings['mytoken']=='somevalue','Token is not saved');
});
```

But as you can see I need to access the home folder. Is there some way to mock the path with some in-memory one and emulate both cases that are windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`package:file`](https://pub.dev/packages/file).  Any function that currently *constructs* `File` or `Directory` objects would need to be changed to take a [`FileSystem`](https://pub.dev/documentation/file/latest/file/FileSystem-class.html) argument and instead would need to call methods on that ([`FileSystem.file`](https://pub.dev/documentation/file/latest/file/FileSystem/file.html) or [`FileSystem.directory`](https://pub.dev/documentation/file/latest/file/FileSystem/directory.html)) to construct equivalent objects.  Typically such `FileSystem` arguments can be optional and can default to `const LocalFileSystem()`.  Note that functions that operate on `File` or `Directory` objects do not need to be changed since `package:file` provides `File` and `Directory` classes that have the same names and that implement the same interfaces as their `dart:io` counterparts.

Tests then can create a [`MemoryFileSystem`](https://pub.dev/documentation/file/latest/memory/MemoryFileSystem-class.html), set it up fake, in-memory files and directories, and pass that to your functions instead.

The typical way you'd enforce using `package:file`'s `File` and `Directory` classes instead of `dart:io`'s is to import `dart:io` only with a prefix:

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;
```

to force its use to be explicit.  If adding `io.` prefixes throughout your code is too onerous, you alternatively can hide any conflicting classes.  For example:

```dart
import 'dart:io' hide File, Directory;
```

Comment: So my class by default can have a `LocalFileSystem` whereas tests can have a `MemoryFileSystem` provided via a setter.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Yes, that's a fine approach if you don't want to add an optional argument to your class's constructor.

Comment: Do `LocalFileSystem` and `MemoryFileSystem` have some common parent class that I can typehint? I mean having the `_filesystem` local variable for filesystem as `dynamic` in that case seems kinda ugly.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Yes, as I mentioned, you should use a reference to a `FileSystem` object.  Note that Dart documentation also indicates the type hierarchy for each class.